# Garbage in uploads folder

Tags: customization

I have massive number of files in my uploads folder. Is there a way of identifying those which are not linked to any post?

Note: some of those files are manually copied to uploads folder not via "media library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be:

1) perform a WordPress XML export ( Dashboard -> Tools -> Export )

2) import into a clean WordPress install ( Dashboard -> Tools -> Import )

At this point, everything in the `/uploads` directory of the clean install is attached. You can now:

3) backup/delete your original `/uploads` directory

4) copy over the `/uploads` directory from the clean install

Comment: Would it be possible to automatically import all manually copied files (as if they were imported via media library)? So I can use built-in feature to detect unlinked files?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: ok. At the moment half of the media files are imported regularly via medial library. I like that. I can go to dashboard->media->un_attached and manage my media files easily (find unattached files)... but the other half is manually copy/pasted into uploads folder so wordpress can't see them... so I can't use the un_attached option

Comment: This plugin lets you recreate your media library from uploads folder

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/

Comment: Now I need to get rid of duplicate attachments... hell

Comment: Add From Server is a great Plugin. I didn't realize from your original question that you mainly wanted to import all images to your database; otherwise, I would have suggested Add From Server. :)

Comment: Yeah, you can't run Add From Server blindly; you need to target images that aren't already in the database, otherwise, you get exactly what you're seeing. (I learned that one the hard way...)